# ping работает без сетевого кабеля

Tags: windows, ping

Выполняю команду пинг адрес1 без сетевого кабеля. В ответ следующее : "ответ от адрес2: заданный узел недоступен" Почему не пишет "превышен нтервал ошидания для запроса"?
В организации локальная сеть. Но сетевой шнур я отключил.

Comment: Потому что система не знает, куда отправить пинг, и соответственно не может его отправить

Comment: можно ли как то получить ответ - превышен интервал ожидания? такой ответ легче обработать в программе

Comment: Чтобы превысился интервал ожидания — нужно сперва отправить icmp-пакет, ответ на который собственно будет ожидаться. Чтобы отправить пакет — нужна подключенная сеть, в которую можно было бы отправить пакет. Так что нет, нельзя.